# store xml data in to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

My Xml file Look Like this type:-

```
    <child_4331 entity_id="4331" value="Region" parent_id="0">
          <child_4332 entity_id="4332" value="Asia" parent_id="4331">
                <child_4333 entity_id="4333" value="India" parent_id="4332">
                      <child_4334 entity_id="4334" value="Karnataka" parent_id="4333" />                    
                </child_4333>
          </child_4332>
    </child_4331>
```

i want to import this file to my sql table
like this:-

```
__________________________________
entity_id     value    parent_id
----------------------------------
  4331       Region        0
----------------------------------
  4332       Asia        4331
----------------------------------
  4333       India       4332 
----------------------------------
  4334     Karnataka     4333
__________________________________
```

i am new in xml file so need the best help to do this.
thanks.

Comment: use simplexml_load_file - http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php to parse the XML and then store the data in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php. Use the object generated to store it in the database.